# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play,src, or click' of null

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, typeerror

Ok so Chrome is give me this error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of null** this keep on popping up if switch it to click or focus function. So in my simple HTML code I have

```
        <audio id="f1Menu" controls>
            <source src="../sounds/menu/menu_f1_help.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
            <source src="../sounds/menu/menu_f1_help.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
        </audio>
        <audio id="f2Menu" controls>
            <source src="../sounds/menu/menu_f2_email.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
            <source src="../sounds/menu/menu_f2_email.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
        </audio>
        <audio id="f3Menu" controls>
            <source src="../sounds/menu/menu_f3_password.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
            <source src="../sounds/menu/menu_f3_password.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
        </audio>
        <audio id="f4Menu" controls>
            <source src="../sounds/menu/menu_f4_enter.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
            <source src="../sounds/menu/menu_f4_enter.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
        </audio>
```

and the the Javascript script which is load on the same page

//this javascript which is attach to html page.

```
     AudioMode().playAudio("f1",2000);

function AudioMode()
{
    this.playAudio = function(key,delay)
    {
            alert(key + "Menu"); //this display on screen with the the id combo im looking for

            //however the document.getElementById is not find it???
            document.getElementById(key + "Menu").play(); 

    }
}
```

If need more info please let me know. I place min code which giving me error the function work just not in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your element hasn't loaded yet. You should wait until it loads.

Replace

```
AudioMode().playAudio("f1",2000);
```

with

```
window.onload=function(){
    AudioMode().playAudio("f1",2000);
}
```

Comment: so say if place this on were calling the script page should work then?

Comment: @Drake just place it instead of AudioMode().playAudio("f1",2000); in the start of your script.